# I can't flag comments from mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, mobile-site

Given the recent emphasis on Being Nice, and flagging comments that are rude or offensive, I was surprised to learn today that I can't flag a comment from the mobile version of the site.

What gives? Do you really want me clogging up the mod-flag queue on answers for this stuff?

Comment: Related MSO post: [How do I delete or flag comments using the mobile website?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100706)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the recent removal of the dedicated mobile site in favour of a [responsive site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/179041) catering to both mobile and desktop, you can now flag comments while on mobile devices.